# Converting a class from C# (AVL tree node) to C

Tags: c#, c, class, struct, avl-tree

I have made a functional non-recursive AVL tree in C#. The node looks like this:

```
class AvlNode
{
     public int data;
     public int balance;
     public AvlNode left;
     public AvlNode right;
     public AvlNode parent;

 }static AvlNode _root = null;
```

The public goes away, add the pointers.

```
struct  
{
     int data;
     int balance;
     struct AvlNode *left;
     struct AvlNode *right;
     struct AvlNode *parent;
}
```

But what do I do with `static AvlNode _root = null;`?

I use it to keep track of the tree root.

Comment: First, give the struct a name (either add a tag after the `struct` keyword, or `typedef` the struct). Then declare a pointer called `_root` and initialize it to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct should be (AvlNode as name of struct)

```
struct AvlNode
{
     int data;
     int balance;
     struct AvlNode *left;
     struct AvlNode *right;
     struct AvlNode *parent;
}
```

Do not use `static` if you have multiple translation units (if entire code is in one .c file then it is ok).

use `extern` for multiple translation units.

Declare `extern struct AvlNode *root;` in your header.

`struct AvlNode *root = NULL;` in your ".c" file.